# How to add all the items of a list box to a textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, listbox

I have a number of `ListBox` items, which I need to copy to a `TextBox`. I have somewhat got it working, but the `TextBox` seems to be adding a `vbnewline` after my `Value1`. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Here is my code:

```vb
TextBox2.Text = ""
For Each I As String In ListBox1.Items
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & I
Next
```

Here is a screenshot because this I can’t post the `TextBox` since it will come out looking the same as the ‘ListBox`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list items probably have newlines in them. ListBox wont show these, but TextBox will

```
TextBox2.Clear()
For Each I As String In ListBox1.Items
    TextBox2.AppendText(I.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ""))
    TextBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

---

Please name your controls something more meaningful than "ListBox1" (how about "_SiteList" ?) or "TextBox2". It takes a couple of seconds to click the (Name) line in the properties grid and type something else, after you drop a control on a form.

By the time you're done adding 27 textboxes, 54 labels, 6 lists, 9 numeric updowns, a few grids, checkboxes, radio buttons etc your entire program code is going to be unbelievably hard to understand and you'll constantly be flicking back and forth between the deisgner and the code wondering "what did I call the textbox with the URL in.. TextBox37, or TextBox38?"

You'll also struggle to get help if your code looks like `TextBox16.Text = List5.Items.Count & If(NumericUpDown38.Value > Grid13.Count, Checkbox62.Checked, Checkbox12.Checked)` - good naming is vital; just think if Microsoft didn't choose clear and relevant property names like `.Text` or `.Items`, coding wouldn't be much fun writing `urlTextBox.String1 = ""` or `For Each x as String in siteList.ObjectCollection1`

Comment: You are my Hero I Mean I have been at this for about 3 days off and on thank you so much